# Type error in python!

Tags: python

```
closedset = set()    


root = (5,6)

for u,v in root:
    if v is not closedset:
       closedset.add(root)
       print closedset
```

Error:

> ```
> for u,v in root:
> ```
>
> TypeError: unpack non-sequence

What should i do with type of error?

Comment: unpack a sequence, of course...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do. Maybe:

```
roots = [(5, 6), (2, 3)]

for u, v in roots:
  if f not in closed:
    closed.add(v)
    print closed
```

Note a few changes:

- `roots` is now a list of tuples. `for u, v in roots` will correctly "unpack" each tuple into `u` and `v`
- by `if v is not closed` your probably meant `if f not in closed`, if `closed` is a dictionary of some kind
- if `close.add` is a method (of a set?), then it has to be called with parens `()` and not brackets `()`

Comment: Actually the problem is:


  keys = child.keys() - here child is a dictionary

  root = keys[0] - so this will return - (5,4)

  Now i need to iterate...for u, v values..I am doing right ??

  closed is a set and the commands I used for it are: 

  closedset = set()

Answer (score 1):

```
root = [(5,6)]
```

...should work.
for iterates through a list or set, returning first u, then v. If you want to return both parts of the set, you'll have to add itself to a list.

Answer (score 0):

```
root = ((5, 6),)
```

or

```
u, v = root
```

Depending on what your intentions are.

Answer (score 0):

```
for u,v in [root]:
   print u,v
```

will do what you want.